# VSCode does not recognize my Flask dependency installed with Poetry

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I am learning how to use VSCode for Python development by building a simple Flask app. I use Poetry for dependency management.

I have a simple `app.py` where I'm importing `flask` and defining a basic route like so:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, Flask!"
```

In the VSCode terminal, I run `poetry shell` and then `python -m flask run`, and the server starts up no problem. I'm able to hit the endpoint and get a response.

However, my VSCode editor is telling me that it's unable to import `flask`. I'm unable to run the VSCode debugger for this reason.

[image]

I'm missing some step. Does anybody have any idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you select the right interpreter in the vscode python extension? `strg+shift+p` and select `Python: Select Interpreter`. A restart of the language server might also help, with `Python: Restart Language Server`.

Comment: Aha! Re-starting VSCode did the trick. I wasn't seeing the Poetry interpreter when I checked via `cmd+shift+p` and `Python: Select Interpreter` prior to re-starting, and now I do. Selecting it fixes the issue. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-starting VSCode did the trick. I wasn't seeing the Poetry interpreter when I looked for it via `cmd+shift+p` and `Python: Select Interpreter` prior to re-starting, and now I do. Selecting the Poetry interpreter it fixes the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your virtualenv poetry project in Vscode.

1. Open Vscode terminal with `Alt`+`T`+`N` and get the path of your poetry virtualenv with this command: `poetry env info`
2. It will show something like this:
   [image]
   You must copy the Executable path
3. Go to the bottom blue bar of Vscode and find the default Python version. Click on it to change it.
   [image]
4. Vscode will ask you for your workspace folder; you must choose the workspace of your project.
5. Then Vscode will show some options, you need to choose `Enter interpeter path`
   [image] You can add your poetry virtualenv copied in the step 2, press `Enter` and it will work fine!